# Why am I getting Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration expected?

Tags: solidity, remix, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

Pardon me, but am a novice to blockchain programming.

Having followed several tutorials on how to use **The OpenZeppelin library** to quicken the solidity development process, I cant seem to shake this following **error message**:

**ParseError: Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration expected.** What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Find below my code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin- 
contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract cryptoTest is ERC721 {

constructor() ERC721("SirNobble in the house", "SNB") public {};

}
```

ParseError: Function, varialbe, struct or modifier declaration expected.

Looking forward to your help!

Comment: Please include the code and not an screenshot, we cannot see the full ingeritance line

Comment: @JulissaDC done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is the semicolon after the constructor function definition.

```js
constructor() ERC721("SirNobble in the house", "SNB")  {

}
```

This should work. Also, the `public` keyword is not required for the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Solidity is just complaining about the semicolon after your function body. Please delete it.